# How do I return Visualization back in flask and display in html using Ajax/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

```
@app.route('/Bar',methods=['POST','GET'])
def Bar():
        x=sns.lineplot(data.da["R&D Spend"],data.da["Profit"])
        return send_file(x)
```

Now how do I do this.
Please answer plain and simple as I'm new to coding.
Please don't use database.

```js
const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST','/Bar',true);
        xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
        xhr.onprogress=function(){
        console.log('hello')
        }

        xhr.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('table1').innerHTML='<img src="this.responseText"';//Here I want to insert visualization
        }
        xhr.send();          
    }
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you can do additional prior research into this topic and follow tutorials elsewhere on the web (such as [this one](http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/creating-charts-with-chart-js-in-a-flask-application/)), and formulate a question based on a more concise issue you may be facing, it would result in a question more suitable for the format here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Posting an answer to this question in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Python Code

```
@app.route('/Bar',methods=['POST','GET'])
def Bar():
    import io
    import base64
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
    ax=sns.set(style="darkgrid")
    sns.lineplot(df.x,df.y)
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    img = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img)
    img.seek(0)
        return send_file(img,mimetype='img/png')
```

```html
const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open('GET','/Bar',true);
              xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
              xhr.onprogress=function(){
              }

              xhr.onload=function(){
                document.getElementById('table1').innerHTML='<img src="/Bar">';
                    
           
              }
            xhr.send();
            }
```